# DX12 one process 2 devices can use the same texture created by one of the devices?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, textures, directx-12

win32 app create 2 devices, device1 and device2(the same adapter).
device1 creates a texture as "ComPtr<::ID3D12Resource> texture", then if device2 can use the texture created by device1?
because the device1 and device2 are in the same process, so device2 has the way to access the "ComPtr<::ID3D12Resource> texture".
("ComPtr<::ID3D12Resource> texture" is not a shared texture)
Thanks

I coded as above, i find it works.
But i donot know if it works by using any other GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create the resource using the flag `D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED`, otherwise, you cannot share the resource between different devices.

You should not use the `ID3D12Resource` instance created by device 1 directly on device 2. Instead, use [CreateSharedHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createsharedhandle) on the resource created by device 1, and then call [OpenSharedHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-opensharedhandle) on device 2 (using that handle) to create a second `ID3D12Resource` instance dedicated to device 2. After that, these two `ID3D12Resource` instances will point to the same resource on the GPU (this resource is now shared).

If your devices are created on different adapters (different GPUs), you must use `D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED_CROSS_ADAPTER` instead of `D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED`.

Comment: But i coded to share one texture between two devices (same process, adapter), it works. The flag is D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE.

Comment: It worked on your machine "by accident", DirectX wasn't designed to work that way, your graphics driver just happened to be not effected by the error of usage. You shouldn't assume that it can work on other machine.

Comment: What about create the texture by D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED. I find it works too. Not use createsharedhandle and opensharddhandle. Device2 just use ComPtr<::ID3D12Resource> texture,device2 can get  it because in the same process.

Comment: You could use D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED to create a [Shared heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/shared-heaps). And I suggest you should use `CreateSharedHandle` and `OpenSharedHandle`.